# Android/Java ArrayList<T> map to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I can't figure out how to map array from stored type to other type.
unfortunately I can't use Java 8.

I have `ArrayList<T>` and I want to map it so I will have `ArrayList<String>`
How can I achieve it?

Let say
`T obj` have method `obj.toString()`

I did google for it. All I can find is how to convert `ArrayList<String>` to `String[]` or `Map<K,V>` to `ArrayList<V>`. That's not what I am looking for :(

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `ArrayList<String> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for(T obj : someList){
   accumulator.add(obj.toString());
}`

Comment: `someList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())`, if you were able to use streams.

Comment: Don't forget to handle `null` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream solution of mapping from some type `T` to `String` like so:

```
ArrayList<String> resultSet =  
           someList.stream()
                   .map(Object::toString) // or ClassName::toString
                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

is the equivalent of:

```
ArrayList<String> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();     
for(T obj : someList)
    accumulator.add(obj.toString());
```

Comment: Does Android support Java 8?

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for answer like this :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i don't use android so i don't know.

Comment: Technically it would be `Object obj`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think recent versions do.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Guava Lists.transform() function.

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List%2C%20com.google.common.base.Function)

```
    Function<T, String> objToString =
            new Function<T, String>() {
                public String apply(T t) { return t != null ? t.toString() : null; }
            };
    List<String> newList = Lists.transform(srcList, objToString);
```